# Tinkercad - Circuit Simulation Failing

Tags: arduino, simulation

Building a simple circuit using Tinkercad, however, this keeps causing the simulation to not load. Arduino is essentially being used as a battery, with no code beyond what is default. If I replace the Arduino with a battery, it all works, as well as if only one push button is connected. Otherwise, the simulation fails to load. Any ideas why?

Link to Tinkercad: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4MQ3nJsZ6or?sharecode=uG_1pgrfRC_uBulytAZZRZ_49-dJq2ygkDL56uEoR5c

[image: Simulation not working]

Comment: are the two voltages the same?

Comment: did you ask Tinkercad?

Comment: A proper circuit please.

Comment: Does Tinkercad always assume, that the Arduino is USB powered?